# how to show full web contents including images in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

the problem i am facing is that, in my web pages, there are some images, which are half on screen because of their size. I have tried UIScrollView but it did not help. So i need to find out a way in which a UIWebView can show my entire content of html, including images, text etc...

Also please let me know how to enable horizontal scroll in UIWebView. Only vertical scroll is working. May be if horizontal scrolling starts to work, my problem gets solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be the page itself, if the CSS contains a wrapper around the entire thing with a width of 100%, it won't scroll horizontally and will just cut things off on smaller screens.  You may want to test with other websites to make sure.

Comment: other website work good.. but my own html page not show horizontal and zooming option (touch inside to zoom).... –

Comment: Then your CSS is almost definitely the culprit.  Try using an absolute value for your width or specify the min-width property on your body tag.

Comment: i don;t think so i have use the same html and css file on android sdk it work alright but on xcode i faces different issue of horizontal scrolling and zooming.......

Comment: Is the html page remotely hosted?  Can you post a URL and I'll poke around the source?  You should try and use Show Blended Layers on the simulator and set the width of your page to something extreme to see what is happening on the clipped side.

Comment: thank u...
but i m not hosting  html pages it is inside my bundle resource ....
vertical scroll work right but horizontal scroll don;t show in fact does not when when i change my orientation of device the remaining part of html from horizontal side show to some extend not full..

Comment: In your HTML, try putting <body style="width: 2000px"> instead of your <body> tag just as a test to rule out the CSS.

Comment: thanks again....
now scroll bar is show and working too...
but still face the same problem the content of html page still show half my images show half and on scroll the other side is blank (white)....

Comment: This is most definitely a problem with your CSS then.  You most likely have a wrapper element that contains all of these images, or your images have an absolute width.  There are a LOT of solutions to this problem. As a simple solution you should set the width explicitly on the container for your images to the maximum size that an image can be.  A More direct solution would require me to see the structure of your HTML.

Comment: mey be u r right but in android sdk it work alright .....
so what should i do android sdk also use tha same css file....

Comment: The solution is usually to make a file that works in both browsers or occasionally you can set parameters based on the browser being used (Chrome for Android and Safari for iOS).  My guess is if you change those values, it won't change the way it looks in android, but will have an effect on the iOS version.

Answer (score 2):

dit you select the "scale page to fit" checkbox in the attributes inspector in your Nib file?
That usually works for me

Comment: yes i have select scale page to fit...
but still face tha same problem horizontal scroll never show ..

Comment: does your page fit in the screen now, or did it help nothing?